# How to specify relative path for parameter "extra" for GWT compiler?

Tags: java, gwt, compiler-construction, localization

How do I can specify relative path for command-line parameter "extra" of GWT compiler ? I need it to generate localization files according to **[this](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinderI18n.html)** tutorial.

I'm on Windows and using IntelliJ IDEA. When I specify it as "-extra /extout" directory "extout" is being created in c:\extout. I tried to specify it as "-extra ./extout" and extras don't get created at all. I don't get it :( I want extras to be created in some folder of my project directory.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually I can't even make it to generate extras for scenario with "-extra /extout". This is totally confusing. It works randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, it's impossible in current version of IDEA.

Also this question is kind of duplicate of **[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070767/is-there-way-to-tell-intellij-idea-which-output-folder-to-use-for-gwt-compiler)**.

Answer (score 1):

I just took a look at the source code to handle the -extra option.

The value you specify is passed directly to java.io.File (new File(yourOption)). I am not sure how you are calling your gwt compiler (what is your current working dir), but if you are working in eclipse -extra extout should be fine

Comment: he's *not* using Eclipse. But that doesn't change the problem: @ruslan, check your working directory for the launch (I don't know IDEA, so can't help more); or maybe you could use variables? Eclipse can do `-extra "${project_loc}/extout"` for instance.

Comment: oops i somehow missed the IDEA :)